# Why is #_template_styles an Invalid Object Name when trying to connect Joomla to SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, joomla

I have migrated my ClearDB MySQL database (for my Joomla website) to an Azure SQL database using the SSMA Migration Assistant. Everything appeared to go OK.

When I try to connect to the new database, however, I get the following error:

```
 Error displaying the error page: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL 
 Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#__template_styles'. SQL=SELECT 
 id, home, template, s.params FROM #__template_styles as s LEFT JOIN 
 #__extensions as e ON e.element=s.template AND e.type='template' AND 
 e.client_id=s.client_id WHERE s.client_id = 0 AND e.enabled = 1: 
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object
 name '#__usergroups'. SQL=SELECT b.id FROM #__usergroups AS a LEFT JOIN 
 #__usergroups AS b ON b.lft <= a.lft AND b.rgt >= a.rgt WHERE a.id = 1
```

Is this due to an incompatability between Joomla and SQL Azure databases or is it due to something I have done wrong in the migration process? And in either case is there something I can do to fix it?

This is new ground for me, so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the substitution of the database prefix is not working. When you say "trying to connect" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I currently have the site running with the mysql database. I then change the connection details in configuration.php to those of the SQL Azure database and when I navigate to the website I get the above error.

Comment: Well something is not working with the database name prefix.  I would go to the joomla SE site [joomla.se] and maybe you would find someone there who has used Azure.